# Neo4j.rb - NameError: undefined local variable or method when using where

Tags: neo4j.rb

I am trying to retrieve all BISAC nodes having the word "Art" in the description.

```
ba = Bisac.where(bisac_value =~ '.*Art.*')
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bisac_value' for main:Object
```

The equivalent cypher query retrieves 10 nodes.

```
MATCH (b:Bisac) WHERE (b.bisac_value =~ '.*Art .*') RETURN b;
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Kaminari from pagination and used will_paginate.
Used page_entries_info

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will certainly work, but an easier one which doesn't resort to using the `Query` API is to simply use a Ruby regular expression:

```
Bisac.all(:l).where(bisac_value: /.*Art.*/)
```

You can even use a case-insensitive regular expression (`/.*Art.*/i`) which will get translated into Cypher syntax as well.

Comment: Also, keep an eye out for new Neo4j.rb screencasts on the Neo4j blog tomorrow.  The sixth episode addresses this, among other thing.

Comment: Is there a way to replace pluck with return? Can't make the version with return to work.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't notice you were `pluck`ing `l`.  You should be able to `return(:l).exec`, though I think you'll need to do a `query` call first, so like `query.return(:l).exec`.  That will give you an object which you can enumerate over and each enumeration will give you a result object which you can call (in this case) the `l` method on

Comment: It is ending in error: ba = Bisac.all(:l).where(bisac_value: /.*Art.*/).return(:l).exec
NoMethodError: undefined method `return' for #<Neo4j::ActiveNode::Query::QueryProxy:0x007fc805352d00>

Comment: Yeah, like I said you need to start with a call to `query`

Comment: Don't know how to do this.

Comment: So you would just do something like `Bisac.all(:l).where(bisac_value: /.*Art.*/).query.return(:l).each {|result| puts result.l.inspect }`.  I take back the need for an `exec` as `Query` object are enumerable by themselves (as long as you're got a `return` in there)

Comment: Got it and worked perfect. I wasn't aware that I should use "query" in the construction. Many thanks for the hint.

Comment: Screencast #6 talks about the difference between proxy objects and query objects some.  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5klM3mD6alLUhNTPTbj5a3GBjU7oZN0t  There's also this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5klM3mD6alLUhNTPTbj5a3GBjU7oZN0t

Comment: Excellent screen cast!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (in the documentation), here is the link:
http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/5.1.x/Querying.html

The query should be:

```
ba = Bisac.all(:l).where("l.bisac_value =~ {the_value}").params(the_value: '.*Art.*').pluck(:l)
```

or, much simpler:

```
ba = Bisac.all(:l).where("l.bisac_value =~ '.*Art.*'").pluck(:l)
```